# Mac and external HD permissions

Tags: external-disk, permission

I'm wondering if my HD gets stolen, and my current permissions are set to:
User: R&W
Staff: R&W
Everyone: R only.

Would anyone be able to plug it to a mac (it's a HFS+ partition) and just read any file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External drives [in fact any drive other than the current boot volume] have zero protection by permission.

It is trivial to Get Info on the volume & set "Ignore ownership on this volume"

[image]

The only way to protect data from any potential bad actor in possession of your drive is to encrypt it.

Comment: Gotcha! I'm better off with File Vault on my external then!